# Middlware shared by errors and normal chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to have a piece of middleware that will establish a variable within the chain of err and non error. How is this possible? Passing err in that callback automatically makes it skip over the normal chain of middleware, and vise-versa, if I remove err it skips over the err chain of middleware...

```
middleware.redirect = function(){
    return function (err, req, res, next){
        if(req.form.redirect){
            req.form_redirect = url.parse(req.form.redirect);
        }else{
            req.form_redirect = url.parse(config.domain);
            req.form_redirect.pathname = "thanks";
        }
        if(err) return next(err);
        return next();
    }
}
```

Comment: The middlewares after yours may discriminate (either act or reject or pass it on to next) between requests on the basis of error value. That is the standard behaviour. What do you want apart from this ? Having parallel error and normal chain is not how you should design them. Middlewares must be heirarchical in their functioning. Each handling the errors or request processed by last.

Comment: @user568109 yeah, but they both share this variable in the chain, and being DRY is of the essence...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error middleware, the one with the signature `(err, req, res, next)` should be the final destination for your route. If you want to add to the `req` object, this needs to be done before an `error` is thrown or `next(new Error())` is called.